# gnome-terminal won't open

Tags: 20.04

My terminal won't open in any form. I tried the Ctrl+ALt+T, I tried opening it from the application interface. I also tried to use the ctrl+alt+f3 terminal and running gnome-terminal but I got

> Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

> #Failed to parse argument: Cannot open display

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Is this a vanilla 20.04 or WSL... given the first hits on google for your error message

Answer (score 1):

a common error is that your locale is wrong, running as root

```
locale-gen
localectl set-locale LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Fixed it for me

Source: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1405049#p1405049